# Multible smb.conf files

Tags: networking, samba, file-sharing

I am new to Ubuntu and Linux and have been having problems with setting up a share folder using samba.  I ran a search in Natilus for smb.conf and found that I have multiple files by that name.  I am sure that having multiple files must be causing at least some of the problems I am having. What folder should the smb.conf file be located in?

The smb.conf file was found in the following folders:

1. /etc/samba          (I understand this to be the preferred folder?)
2. /home/craig/BackUp Files    (this is a back up I made of the default file)
3. /usr/share/samba
4. /usr/share/doc/nautilus-share/examples

Which folders should the smb.conf file be in?  How could I have gotten so many smb.conf files on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my question I had four locations containing a smb.conf file.  As stated, the  preferred folder is the /etc/samba folder.  I since deleted all of the other smb.conf files except for the backup file with no adverse effects.