# In what file is the information stored when you share a folder using Locale Network Share

Tags: networking, samba

In what file is the information stored when you share a folder using Locale Network Share?  I am trying to figure out why when I shutdown and restart my system my shared folders revert back to unshared folders?

This question relates to my question on [losing locale network share settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887832/losing-locale-network-share-settings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `find` and `grep` Here's how you can narrow down your search.

Create or modify a share in the usual way. This should look familiar:

[image]

Then immediately open a terminal and issue the command

`sudo find / -cmin -1 | grep samba`

This will provide a list of all the files that have changed in the past minute with the string "samba" which is what the local network share uses.

I tested this by sharing my Music folder and running the above command which resulted in the output shown.

```
find: `/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
/run/samba/dbwrap_watchers.tdb
/run/samba/smbXsrv_open_global.tdb
/run/samba/serverid.tdb
/run/samba/smbXsrv_tcon_global.tdb
/run/samba/smbXsrv_session_global.tdb
/run/samba/msg.lock
/var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock
/var/lib/samba/usershares
/var/lib/samba/usershares/music
/var/lib/samba/winbindd_cache.tdb
```

This narrows it down considerably and allowed me to answer your [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887832/losing-locale-network-share-settings)

Comment: I created the share and then ran sudo find / -cmin -1 | grep samba  but none of the files it returned looked like it contained the file share information?

Comment: you don't have anything in  `/var/lib/samba/usershares` ?

Comment: Nothing comes up in the /var/lib/samba/usershares after running sudo find / -cmin -1 | grep samba

Comment: I removed the share, then added the share again and ran  sudo find / -cmin -1 | grep samba    
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/run/samba/dbwrap_watchers.tdb
/run/samba/msg.lock
find: ‘/proc/20135/task/20135/fd/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/20135/task/20135/fdinfo/6’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/20135/fd/5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/proc/20135/fdinfo/5’: No such file or directory
/var/lib/samba/usershares
/var/lib/samba/usershares/share
/var/lib/samba/private/msg.sock

This time the folder  /var/lib/samba/usershares/share  appeared?

Comment: That's not surprising is it? -cmin -1 selects for files that have changed in the past minute. If this question is answered to your satisfaction, please accept it so that others with the same question can find good answers.  It's also how we say thanks here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it solved my question on where the information is stored.  Now if I can just figure out why I can not access the shared folders I will be all set.  Could I please ask you to take a look at my related questions and see if you can suggest any possible fixes to help me gain access.

Comment: To which related questions do you refer? {this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-answer) explains how to link to an answer, but the process is the same for linking to a question.

Comment: The questions I am talking about are those that I have posted trying to figure out why I can not access the shared folders on my LAN.   http://askubuntu.com/questions/890521/network-error-message-when-trying-to-connect-from-external-source  http://askubuntu.com/questions/889510/not-showing-up-on-network-after-running-system-config-samba  http://askubuntu.com/questions/889237/can-not-access-ubuntu-shared-folders-from-windows-computer